# dynamic dependancy added when module is called

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am still quite new to angular and perhaps I have the wrong end of the stick in my design here but I am trying to create a re-usable widget, a dropdown menu (html select).
This dropdown menu will contain a list of options.

What I would like to do is create a generic dropdown widget that can have its contents added at runtime by specifying the dependencies when the module is run.

In the dependency list of the module i would like to define what factory to use to then fill the html select with options

currently what I have is:

```
   angular.module('web_dropDown', ['optionsFactory'])
```

is it possible for me to define "optionsFactory" on the fly so that the same module can be used to create dropdown menus with different contents?

Comment: If I understand your requirement right, you need to create a directive and you can pass the data to it. This way you can reuse the dropdown anywhere. See the angular documentation for more details. This article  (http://www.ng-newsletter.com/posts/directives.html ) may also help.

Comment: Hi there, thanks for the link, its a really good description on directives, yes you are correct, i should have noted that in my question. I am creating a directive and the directive is dependent on a factory for passing it the data necessary to fill the options list, currently the factory is defined in the directive dependency list but I would like to add the factory dynamically - i.e when including the directive in the main html, is it possible to do this?

Comment: From what i understand when i use a directive in my html i can use it like so:

Comment: I am assuming that your data for the dropdown directive is varying (and coming from different sources). In that case, expose the data on the scope (in controller) and pass it to the directive using that.